# C++ compiler optimization

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-optimization

Will modern C++ compilers (including `gcc`) optimize the following (macro-like) code?

```
    template<typename F, typename ...A>
    err foo(F fn, A&&... args)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<A>(args)...) ? get_last_error() : err();
    }
```

For example, can it optimize the following code

```
    return foo(test, 5, 20, "bar");
```

to:

```
    return test(5, 20, "bar") ? get_last_error() : err();
```

Comment: Try it and see! `gcc -O2 -S` is your friend.

Comment: You're asking if modern compilers are capable of inlining..?

Comment: Yes. Inlining a function with variadic template parameters.

Comment: I would be astounded if they couldn't -- inlining is done by the compiler backend while variadic templates are strictly a frontend concept.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is called "perfect forwarding" (that's the term to google if you want to learn more in depth about it), and C++11 supports it thanks to r-value references. So the answer is yes, it will get fully optimized.